# flink disk usage in job manager increases after every job submission over rest

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

I have deployed my own flink setup in AWS ECS. One Service for JobManager and one Service for task Managers. I am running one ECS task for job manager and  3 ecs tasks for TASK managers.

I have a kind of batch job which I upload using flink rest every-day with changing new arguments, when I submit each time disk memory getting increased by ~ 600MB, I have given a checkpoint as S3 . Also I have set **historyserver.archive.clean-expired-jobs** true .

Since I am running on ECS, not able to find why the memory is getting increased on every jar upload and execution.

What are the flink config params I should look to make sure the memory is not shooting up on every new job upload?

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration.
blob.service.cleanup.interval:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#blob-service-cleanup-interval

historyserver.archive.retained-jobs:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#historyserver-archive-retained-jobs

Comment: Link can broke sometimes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30401284)